# Epplus add values to a range of cells

Tags: c#, excel, epplus

In C#, using `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` , you can assign values to an entire row at once like this:

```
string[] headings = { "Value1", "Value2", "Value3" };
excelSheet.get_Range("A1:C1", Type.Missing).Value2 = headings;
```

Is there any similar functionality provided in the EPPlus library?

Answer (score 7):

You could use the `.LoadFromCollection` method.

So, for example:

```cs
var vals = new string[] { "value1", "value2", "value3" };
var rng = sheet.Cells["A1:A3"];

rng.LoadFromCollection(vals);
```

will produce this output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your response, but your suggestion didn't work. Your code adds rows in a column, the question is about adding columns in a row. Even after modifying the range to address columns instead of rows, it only populated the first column.

Comment: LoadFromCollection only works vertically. There is no option (at this moment) to have it work horizontally.

Answer (score 4):

A little clunky but here is an example.

```
// A row of numbers
var numbers = new List<object> {1.1, 2.2, 3.3};
var horizontalRange = sheet.Cells[$"A1:A{numbers.Count}"];
horizontalRange.LoadFromArrays(new List<object[]> {numbers.ToArray()});

// a grid
var colours = new object[] { "red", "green", "blue"};
var range2d = sheet.Cells["A3:C4"];
range2d.LoadFromArrays(new List<object[]> { numbers.ToArray(), colours });
```

[image]