# Writing a string list to excel using a range C#

Tags: c#, excel

I have an excel range:

```
   Excel.Range range = Worksheet.get_Range("A1","A7");
```

And a string list:

```
// The list contains the same amount of elements as cells in the range
List<string> AcollumnValues = getList();
```

My code so far:

```
        Excel.Application App = new Excel.Application();
        Excel.Workbook Workbook = App.Workbooks.Open(sourceASettings["file"]);
        Excel._Worksheet Worksheet = Workbook.Sheets[1];


        Excel.Range range = Worksheet.get_Range("A1","A4") userSupliedRangeArray[1]);
        List<string> valuesToWrite = getValuesToWrite();
```

How can I write the string list to the excel using the range?

Comment: Maybe there's a way of doing it directly, but you can iterate through the list and write the values one by one .

Comment: @sagi I was indeed looking for a direct way, But if it only can be achieved by Iteration and you post an answer using that method will certainly appreciate that.

Comment: If you are able to use `EPPlus` you might be able to use `LoadFromCollection`

Comment: Found an example of `EPPlus` `LoadFromCollection` https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34882275/epplus-add-values-to-a-range-of-cells

Comment: I second using EPPlus. Makes working with Excel files a lot easier

Comment: Ah, @matt link has the right solution for you.

Comment: @sagi feel free to edit into your answer, if you can make it suitable for OP

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You'll maybe need to adjust this and fix some minor issues, but it should do the trick (Uses EPPlus):

```
int counter = 1;
foreach (string str in AcollumnValues) {
   worksheet.Cells["A" + counter].Value = str;
   counter++;
}
```